# Extracting raster values to polygon: error "arguments imply differing number of rows:1549, 0"

Tags: raster, r, polygon, error, extract

I am trying to extract the mean of a raster data to polygons with the following code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maptools) 

agri_suitability=raster("suit")
regions <- readShapeSpatial("Regions.shp") #SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

plot(agri_suitability)
plot(regions, add=T)
```

[image]

```
polygon_agri_suitability=extract(agri_suitability,regions,fun=mean,na.rm=T)
regions@data = data.frame(regions@data, polygon_agri_suitability)

write.csv(regions,"suitability_mean.csv")
```

After data.frame I get an error:

> arguments imply differing number of rows:1549, 0

My "Regions.shp" file in fact includes 1549 rows. But I don't know what this error means and how I can solve it.

Comment: polygon_agri_suitability turns a csv file including variables from the polygon layer but nothing from raster data.

Comment: I don't understand rest of your questions. But the code works with other polygon layers, and I don't understand what's different about this specific polygon layer ("Regions.shp").

Comment: what do you mean by "clip with SpatialPolygons object"? where in the code you are referring to? what's the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78680/discussion-between-andre-silva-and-d-b).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Thanks to @AndreSilva, I found the problem and the solution.</sub>

The problem was that the polygon and raster layers had different geographic systems. So I used Data Management `Project` tool of ArcMap to get both layers in WGS 1984. Now, the polygon layer exactly overlaps with the raster map, and the code works correctly.